# Promisify `execFile` is not resolving when opening a dmg file

Tags: node.js, node-promisify

This is an extremely weird bug I'm running into. Basically, I have this `execFile`:

`export const execFile = util.promisify(childProcess.execFile);`

When I use this to open up a dmg file that is currently mounted, it opens up the application, but it doesn't call the `.then()` portion.

I tested this in node console too, and it's the same thing:

Here's the snippet I'm running in node console:

```
async function openAnyDesk() {
    console.log("hi");
    const { stdout } = await execFile(
      "/Volumes/AnyDesk/AnyDesk.app/Contents/MacOS/AnyDesk"
    );

    console.log("wtf?");
    console.log("stdout", stdout);
  }
```

```
> openAnyDesk()
hi
Promise {
  <pending>,
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 644,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 5,
  [Symbol(destroyed)]: { destroyed: false }
}
>
```

Currently stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks like I misunderstood *when* the promise actually gets resolved. It'll only get resolved once the application exits, not on opening.

Found this gem: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/34234